# Ativar animate.css apenas quando objeto for clicado

Tags: html5, css-animations

Como adicionar o efeito de animação apenas quando o objeto for clicado? Já estou utilizando animações com o animate.css, mas gostaria que o efeito iniciasse apenas quando eu clicar em cima. Como fazer isso?

Comment: Pode demonstrar com código o que ja fez, por favor?

Comment: mas eu não sei como faz, por isso estou perguntando =) só estou usando animação simples. Por exemplo: <h1 class="animated shake">Animação quando clica</h1>. Daí a animação ocorre assim q eu atualizo a página, mas quero que ela inicie somente depois que eu clicar nesse h1, entendeu?

Comment: Fizeram uma edição aí colocando jQuery. A @RafaelaLopes está realmente a usar jQuery ou não? Essa informação não estava aí inicialmente.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters desculpe se deixe as coisas confusas, eu mesmo tinha incluido as tag novas, pois elas foram usadas para fazer o Click na animação, apenas por fins de pesquisa no futuro etc, já que foram usados na resposta. Sem o js seria mais complexo fazer o gatilho da animação como as classes originais do animated.css

Comment: @hugocsl eu até entendi seu ponto. Relativamente, as coisas com jQuery costuma (ou costumava) ser mais simples, mas no caso em questão, observe que seu código praticamente tem a mesma quantidade de linhas que a do Guilherme.

Comment: @hugocsl as tags tem que ser relevante ao problema e não as respostas, as respostas podem se enquadrar nas tags ou ir além e só. Se eu desse uma resposta que usasse SVG de alguma forma combinado com animate.css isso não tornaria certo colocar a tag SVG na pergunta.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sim com certeza seria a opção mais coerente caso ela já não esteja usando jQuery no projeto. Concordo com vc. E sobre as tags estou até lendo isso aqui rss https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3829/adicionar-tags-as-respostas

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento pois é estou até lendo sobre isso no Meta aqui :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com jQuery, você pode adicionar a class do Animated.css em uma função `click`.

***Edit.*** Na documentação existem alguns métodos para verificar o fim da animação, sendo assim inclui na resposta essa opção para o usuário poder clicar e fazer a animação sempre que quiser *(agradecimento ao sr. @dvd pela ajuda)*

Veja o exemplo

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".box").on("click", function(){
    var box = $(this);
    var classes = "animated wobble";
    box.addClass(classes)
    .on("animationEnd oAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd webkitAnimationEnd", function(){
        box.removeClass(classes);
    });
});
});
```

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box {
 cursor: pointer;
 display:inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <div class="box">
        <img src="http://placecage.com/100/100">
    </div>
```

Comment: que simples!!! deu certo! Muito obrigada!

Comment: @RafaelaLopes olha o edite que fiz, agora sempre ao final da animação o usuário tem a chance de clicar novamente para ver o efeito caso vc deseje isso. Mas se não quiser deixe como estava antes

Comment: Se está usando o `animate.css`, não seria perda de processamento a toa usar jQuery?

Comment: Wallace Maxters o nome pode confundir um pouco as coisas, mas na verdade o animate.css é um framework 100% css. Entra no link dele e da uma olha no link de Download que tem lá  https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ Sem o jQueri ela teria que usar un chackbox para adicionar e remover as classes no Click. animate.css não tem JS originalmente para isso

Comment: @WallaceMaxters na verdade acabei de ver o código fonte do próprio projeto e se vc reparar lá no final do doc tem um script, inclusive em jQuery que ele usa para executar os exemplos da página ao clicar no btn "Animate It"

Comment: É, você tem razão. A própria doc ensinar usar jQuery [o que acho bem desnecessário, já que o jQuery tem uma porrada de funções de animação].

Comment: O AP já pode estar utilizando jQuery na página.

Comment: Bem melhor usar animação com CSS do que as do jQuery. :D

Comment: @dvd vi que vc fez um exemplo até melhor que o meu, eu não tinha reparado que na documentação tinham os eventos do final da animação. Se o sr. não se importar posso incluir na minha resposta?

Comment: Claro pô, à vontade.

Comment: @dvd pois é, mas agora que eu vi que a pergunta foi editada. Quando fiz o comentário, acho que as tags não estava lá. Acho que o AP acabou não especificando tal coisa. De qualquer forma, se a própria lib incentiva usar jQuery, fazer o quê, né? Ultimamente, tenho sido um evangelizador anti-jQuery

Comment: @WallaceMaxters eu particularmente gosto mais das animações do CSS pois vc consegue controla-las mais fácil, usando delays, parando no final, usando cubic-bezier etc, pode controlar os fragmentos da animação e cada elemento que vai ser animado de forma mais simples, prefiro deixar o jQuery nesse caso apenas para fazer o "trigger", mas isso vai de cada um, eu tenho mais facilidade com css então prefiro ir nessa

Comment: @dvd fico agradecido, inclui os créditos []´s

Comment: @hugocsl a ideia de ter um "trigger" eu acho até boa, só não gosto de carregar todo o resto do jQuery. Eu até acho que tem umas libs alternativas (mais leves) que o jQuery.

Answer (score 6):

**Não precisa colocar um biblioteca inteira e relativamente pesada como jQuery só para usar animate.css**

basta adicionar as classes com `.className` ao elemento desejado, e usar os eventos `webkitAnimationEnd`, `mozAnimationEnd`, `MSAnimationEnd`, `oanimationend` e `animationend` (eventos para browsers antigos e novos, para manter a compatibilidade) para detectar quando a animação terminou

Exemplo quando clicar no h1:

```js
var foo = document.querySelector('#foo');

foo.addEventListener('click', function () {
    foo.className = 'animated bounce';
});

foo.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', removeClass);
foo.addEventListener('mozAnimationEnd', removeClass);
foo.addEventListener('MSAnimationEnd', removeClass);
foo.addEventListener('oanimationend', removeClass);
foo.addEventListener('animationend', removeClass);

function removeClass()
{
   foo.className = '';
}
```

```css
h1 {
    color: #f35626;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(92deg,#f35626,#feab3a);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    font-size: 48pt;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">

<h1 id="foo">Stack Overflow</h1>
```

exemplo quando clicar em outro elemento:

```js
var foo = document.querySelector('#foo');
var botao = document.querySelector('#animar');

botao.addEventListener('click', function () {
    foo.className = 'animated bounce';
});

foo.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', removeClass);
foo.addEventListener('mozAnimationEnd', removeClass);
foo.addEventListener('MSAnimationEnd', removeClass);
foo.addEventListener('oanimationend', removeClass);
foo.addEventListener('animationend', removeClass);

function removeClass()
{
   foo.className = '';
}
```

```css
h1 {
    color: #f35626;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(92deg,#f35626,#feab3a);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    font-size: 48pt;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">

<h1 id="foo">Stack Overflow</h1>

<button id="animar">Animar</button>
```